# How to change the path for Flutter SDK - Linux

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

So far I have downloaded two different version for the flutter SDK.

One is **v2.10.2**  and another is **v2.5.3**.

Currently Flutter is installed in my Linux system with **v2.10.2** but the version 2.5.3 is required to run the old flutter project.

So, I required to downgrade the flutter version. So, How can I change the Path for the flutter SDK from terminal ?

I have tried below way :

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/jaiminmodi/snap/flutter/common/v2.5.3/flutter_linux_2.5.3-stable/flutter/bin"
```

But still while checking flutter version its showing 2.10.0

What might be the issue ? Thanks.

Comment: `export PATH="$PATH:..."` won't help you if the path to the Flutter 2.10.0 installation is already in `PATH`.  You could do `export PATH="/your/path/to/2.5.3:$PATH"` so that your 2.5.3 installation takes precedence.   Alternatively, if you don't need to frequently switch between the two versions, I'd keep only one installation and then run `git checkout` in it to the version you want.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use fvm

https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/installation

It'll take care of everything you just need to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

**I can help you with windows. I don't have prior knowledge in Linux but looking at windows procedure you will understand something.**

**First, download both v2.10.2 and v2.5.3 zip files and extract them in a folder like the following for v2.10.2 its name flutter, and for v2.5.3 its name flutter253.**

**In my case, I have two versions latest and v1.22.6.**
[image]

**Now create one folder named aliases.**

[image]

**Create two batch windows files named flutter and flutter253.
In my case, it's flutter and flutter1226.**

[image]

**Now edit both files using notepad and add the following line.
for the latest version add code (Add your latest flutter version bin path)**

```
@echo off
D:\"Program files"\flutter\bin\flutter %*
```

**for another version add the following code  (Add your v2.5.3 flutter version bin path in my case it was v1.22.6 means flutter1226 folder bin path you will be flutter253)**

```
@echo off
D:\"Program files"\flutter1226\bin\flutter %*
```

**Now add aliases folder path in your user and system path environment variables like the following (I highlighted the image)**

**1. User**

[image]

**2. System**

[image]

**Congrats! it's done now you can you both versions by running commands like**

```
flutter --version and
flutter253 --version in my case it's flutter1226 --version
```

[image]

**Now to add it's in your vscode do as the following image**

**1. go to settings and search dart SDK**

[image]

**2. by clicking the flutter version below you can change the SDK version. [image]**